# JavaScript file connecting issue

Tags: javascript, html

I am experiencing strange behavior when connecting to my JS file. The index.html file is in the root of the project. In a folder named JS I have a JS file called main.js.

This is the folder path I am using in my html file:

```
<p id="demo"></p>    
<script src="js/main.js">
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = add(int1, int2);
</script>
```

And my JS code in main.js file is the following:

```
    //add two int

function add(int1, int2) {
    return int1+int2
}

var int1 = 5
var int2 = 9
var sum = int1+int2

console.log(sum)
```

I am getting the console log output of 14 as expected but no HTML output.
But if I remove the path for the external js file and put all the js code in the HTML file with following code:

```
<script>
    //add two int
    function add(int1, int2) {
        return int1+int2
    }
    var int1 = 5;
    var int2 = 4;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = add(int1, int2);
</script>
```

Then I get the HTML output. What have I missed out?

Comment: You can't put inline JavaScript inside a `<script>` with a "src" attribute.

Comment: [Quoting the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) - "If a script element has a src attribute specified, it should not have a script embedded inside its tags".

Comment: In other words, a `<script>` either gets the code externally or from the embedded code, not both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If the `src` attribute is present, the `<script>` element must be empty.

Source: [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_script.asp)